# Repeat only middle of divider background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok so I have a divider image that has the top and bottom parts fading like so:
[image]
Can I use a sprite and 3 DIV's for repeating only the middle part of it? I have to mention that my height is variable. How can I do something like that? Do I need 3 images (top, middle and bottom) ?

Current HTML & CSS code for this:

```
HTML:
<div class="left-side">
</div>
<div class="vdiv25p"></div>
<div class="right-side"></div>

CSS:
.left-side {
display: inline-block;
width: 720px;
}

.vdiv25p {
display: inline-block;
width: 24px;
height: 658px;
background-image: url(../images/vdiv-large.png);
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.right-side {
width: 236px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

P.S. I know how to do it with JavaScript or jQuery but I was wondering if there was a CSS-only solution :)

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you are asking. Is there any way you could clarify? You want to know how to make the middle image adjust its height to 100% of the .left-side div? And then take the width of the div and subtract a height of what?

Comment: @AaronSiciliano it's pretty self explanatory, I want that divider to stretch to the height of the element on the left, if it were a simple 1x1 image it would have been simple, but my client requires the divider to have those fading parts at the end and bottom, do you understand now? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i understand what you are asking for now. Please correct me if i am misunderstanding.

http://jsfiddle.net/6fowh58o/

```
.vdiv25p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 658px;
    background-image: url("http://www.artwork.com/press_rl/solid.gif"),url("http://www.artwork.com/press_rl/solid.gif"), url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/38/Rect_Geometry.png/220px-Rect_Geometry.png");
    background-position: top, bottom, center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-y;
    background-size: 100% 10%, 100% 10%, 100% 10%;
```

}

This code achieves what i believe you are looking for. Setting multiple background images inside of one div (3 in this example). One image is set to the top (backgroud-position), one to the bottom, and one to the center. The order that the images are specified in the (background-image) attribute sets what (Z-index like effect) they will have against each other. The background size is telling the objects what (width,height) they will take of their parent element. To achieve the repeated center image you can use the normal (background-repeat) values.